# Custom validation message within a multiple input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, haml

So I have this form that is in relation to creating some promo codes for an app that I work on. I also need the user to chose a location in order to successfully have a promo code to properly work. I did this by adding a validation in the model like

```
validates_presence_of :locations
```

Now this works well in that it does not allow the user to continue until the user adds a location.  However I wanted to create an error message informing the user what they missed, and this is ultimately my problem. I tried:

```
validates_presence_of :locations, :message => "Location is Required"
```

However I'm not getting the error message to render.  I believe the problem has something to do with my form because instead of asking the user to type a location, i'm asking them to select a location.

Here is my view

```
.control-group
   = f.label :location_ids, "Locations", class: 'control-label'
      .controls
        = f.select :location_ids, Location.accessible_by(current_ability, :manage).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, :class => 'chzn-select', :'data-placeholder' => 'Select locations', :multiple => true
```

I don't really want to go into my `config/locales/en.yml` and make edits. I will certainly do it if I have to, but if its possibly to sidestep editing that guy I will.

If anybody has any ideas on what i'm missing with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Well, do 1 thing. Replace `{}` with `{prompt: 'Select locations'}` .. and remove `:'data-placeholder' => 'Select locations'` .. Now try again.

Comment: I looked into that as a solution......but nothing changed. :(

Comment: I think the problem is indeed that the error message from your validations is being added to :location not to :location_ids. Is it showing at all that there is a validation error on location_ids and just the wrong message, or nothing?

Comment: Btw. why you don't like to use your locales file? Even if you don't plan  a multilingual app it is good practice to keep translated strings out of your application, and have them in one place.

Comment: So i'm not getting a validation error at all. One thing I am noticing is if I move the prompt to the place you had it, I get a generic placeholder information for the user, but no error message of any kind is popping up. As for your other comment, you definitely have a good point, i'll have to look into that as well.